# Making a variable globally available to all modules in next.js application

Tags: webpack, next.js

Is it possible to make a variable globally available to all modules within a next.js application so I don't have to import it wherever I need it?

This can be very useful for things such as utilities that are commonly used in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js doesn't expose a initialization script or even a init hook where you can execute some code. So, in short it is close to impossible.

Having said that, you can still achieve this partially! You can either use the Next.js with either Page router or App router. Further, if you are using Edge runtime instead of Node.js runtime, then it may create problems. And finally, this technique will not work for accessing globals inside the middleware.

If you are using **Page router**, you can create a custom [`App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app) component and use the `globalThis` to achieve this.

```
// pages/_app.jsx

if (!globalThis.myGlobalHello) {
  globalThis.myGlobalHello = () => console.log('Hello');
}
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

If you are using TypeScript, then you will have to declare global somewhere by creating `*.d.ts` file somewhere in the `src` folder:

```
declare global {
  var myGlobalHello: () => void;
}
```

If you are using **App router**, you can do exactly the same thing using with [Root Layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required) `app/layout.jsx` or `app.layout.tsx` file.

> Using global variables is feels quick and easy way to do things, but it is like going back to the old way of writing JavaScript and ignoring all the good things that ES Modules stand for. Things become complex when it comes to writing unit and integration tests, especially when your global variables are non-serializable (like functions). Finally, if you are doing deep imports for your utility modules, then consider using [`aliases`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Environment Variables.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)

Create a file called `.env.local` in your root and define your variables there.

For example you can define variables like:

```
FIRST_NAME="John"
LAST_NAME="Smith"
```

And you can access it anywhere in your project like:

```js
var fullName = process.env.FIRST_NAME + process.env.LAST_NAME;
```

Big thing to note is that you will have to redefine these variables in all the environments you have your project deployed in.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was looking for something more flexible so I can define functions and objects globally. That's why I mentioned utilities.

Comment: @NojanA. Wrapping your app component with a global context may help as shown in this [article](https://www.travisluong.com/simple-global-state-management-in-next-js/)

Comment: If that link answers your question I can add it as an another separate answer than just this comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was thinking about something that cuts right into the Webpack module system and enables a variable globally. @TP95